# how to import .mysql file into the MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, import

I have to import a data file `news120M_stanford_lemma_np_pruned.mysql` into the new database on MySQL 5.5 but getting an error :

```
mysql> mysql -u username -p -h localhost jobim_stanf < C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\Jobim_Stanf.mysql
ERROR:
Unknown command '\P'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\M'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\M'.
```

What is the correct command for importing such file?

Answer (score 0):

The command is correct :

```
mysql -u {username} -p {databasename} < file_name.sql
```

The problem is the spaces in your `path` of the sql file. You'll probably have to add quotation marks `""` around it :

```
mysql -u username -p -h localhost jobim_stanf < "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\Jobim_Stanf.mysql"
```

Comment: In general, the quotation marks around the path with spaces is necessary, indeed. But in this case it's all about "\" while mysql expecting "/" . Changing  it this way and using "source" command, all files were imported without errors.